# JSON Serlization and Deserilization

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs

I have Spring Boot Application that returns response of object. My Response Object(s) structure are as follows :

AddtlParams {

List of AdtlParam

}

AdtlParam {

```
String key
List<String> values
```

}

I need response in JSON as follows using XML Annotations

AddtlParams : {

param1 : [pama1-value],

param2 : [pama2-value],

.
.

paramn : [parman-value],

}

XML return correctly but JSON format contains AdtlParams List Tag. How can that to b avoided and get above format JSON Response

Answer (score 0):

class AdditionalParamsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List> {

```
String sValue = "";

@Override
public void serialize(List<AdditionalParam> lstApms, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    gen.writeStartObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < lstApms.size(); ++i) {
        AdditionalParam ap = lstApms.get(i);
        serialize(ap, gen);
    }
    gen.writeEndObject();
}

private void serialize(AdditionalParam ap, JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
    gen.writeFieldName(ap.getName());
    gen.writeStartArray();

    if ((null != ap.getValue()) && (!ap.getValue().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
        sValue = ap.getValue();
    }

    if ((null != ap.getValues()) && (!ap.getValues().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
        sValue = ap.getValues().stream().map(n -> String.valueOf(n)).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
    }

    if (!sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        gen.writeString(sValue);
    else {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    gen.writeEndArray();
    sValue = "";
}
```

}